# How can i make my custom command available to all user in linux

Tags: command

I have written a custom command under user 'krishna' on my laptop, and now i want it to be available for other all user without redefining to each user. For now, i have defined the command in /home/krishna/.bashrc As this file exist under user krishna and work only for krishna. is there any way i can defile it globally for all users?

Comment: Copy the comand to a directory that's in everyone's search path, which might be `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the command in the `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` file (which one depends on your distribution). One of these should exist on your machine.

Commands you define in your local `/home/[USER]/.bashrc` are only available for [USER].
Commands or aliases defined in `/etc/bashrc` are available for all users.

Comment: Thank you. adding alias into /etc/bash.bashrc worked for me.